Can you inject $ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*} $ into $ S_n $?
It's possible to inject the semidirect product (where  $ (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*} $ maps to $ \text{Aut} (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) $ using the identity map) by defining a group action as (a,b) * x = a + bx.
I'm curious whether there are tools we can use for the direct product instead of the semidirect product.
This doesn't work for the direct product if $ n = 3 $ since it produces $ Z_6 $ using CRT and not $ S_3 $. Can we prove that it doesn't work in general?

For $n=3$ this is already impossible.

(concerning my edits: apologies, I've misread the question initially)

She's referring to the holomorph.   It says using the identity homomorphism.   @ThomasAndrews

@KentaS I see why it doesn't work for $ n = 3 $. Can you prove that it doesn't work in general?

I believe we can say in $S_n$ that the only elements that commute with an $n$-cycle are powers of that $n$-cycle. So it isn't possible when $n$ is a prime power.

To find a counterexample we'd probably need to find an example $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_m^{a_m}$  where $\phi(n)=q_1^{b_1}\cdots q_k^{b_k}$ and $$\sum p_i^{a_i} +\sum q_j^{b_j}\leq n.$$ I feel pretty certain we can find such $n,$ but it won't be a small value of $n.$

Actually, $n=12$ gives an example where it is possible. $1\in\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z\mapsto (1\,2\,3\,4)(5\,6\,7)$ and in the group of units, $5\mapsto (8\,9)$ and $7\mapsto (10\,11).$
This is because $n=2^2\cdot 3$ and $\phi(n)=2^2$ and we have that $2^2+3+2^2\leq 12.$
There are no examples when $n$ is a prime power, I believe, though I can't prove it. But most other cases do.
In particular, if you can factor $n=ab$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a+b-1\leq \frac{ab}2,$ then we can find such a subgroup. But this inequality is equivalent to $(a-2)(b-2)\geq 2.$ This will cover a lot of examples.
Basically, we are using the fact that there is an obvious homomorphism $S_{n_1}\times\cdots\times S_{n_k}\to S_{n_1+\cdots+n_k},$ and factoring your product group into smaller groups.

Recall that for any $a,b \geq 1$, $S_a \times S_b$ embeds in $S_{a+b}$. This is the main fact that we will use.
Suppose that $n$ is a prime power and assume you have an injective map $f: \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \rightarrow S_n$.
Then $f(1,1)$ is an element of order $n$, so it is a $n$-cycle $c$. Now, if $x \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, then $f(1,x)$ commutes to $c$ so is a power of $c$.
For the other cases, we use Thomas Andrews’s argument.
Suppose that $n=ab$ with $a,b$ coprime and $a+\varphi(a)+b+\varphi(b) \leq n$, then $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \simeq \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \times \mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ injects in $S_{a+\varphi(a)+b+\varphi(b)}$ which injefts into $S_n$.
If in the above one has $a,b \geq 3$, then one has $a+\varphi(a) + b+\varphi(b) \leq 2a+2b-2$, and $n-(2a-2b-2)=(a-2)(b-2)-2$, so the inequality fails only if $a=b=3$, which is impossible.
When $a=2$, and $b$ has a divisor $1 < b < d$ (so that $d$ is odd) then $b+\varphi(b)+2+\varphi(2)=b+b-d+3=n-d+3 \leq n$, so we are done.
The only remaining case is $n=2p$ with $p$ odd prime.
Then $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
Write $p-1=ds$ with $d>1$ a power of $2$ and $s$ odd. If $s>1$, then $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ injects in $S_{d+s+2}$, and $p-(d+s+2)=(d-1)(s-1)-2$ is always non-negative, so the answer is positive.
Finally, we’re stuck with $n=2p$ with $p$ Fermat, and we wish to embed $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ in $S_{2p}$.
Suppose we have such an embedding $f$.
Then the image of $(1,0,0)$ is an element of $S_{2p}$ with order $p$: it is either a $p$-cycle, or a product of two $p$-cycles whose support is a partition of $\{1,\ldots,2p\}$.
If $f(1,0,0)$ is a $p$-cycle, we can assume that it is the cycle $(1\,2\,\ldots\,p)$, whose centralizer is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times S_p$. Thus, by cardinality, $f$ induces an injective morphism $g: \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow S_p$.
Since $p-1$ is a power of $2$, $g(0,1)$ must be a $(p-1)$-cycle, say $g(0,1)=(1\,\ldots\,p-1)$.
Now, $g(1,0)$ has order $2$, so is a product of transpositions, so it has a fixed point. Since $Fix(g(1,0))$ is stable under $Fix(g(0,1))$, $Fix(g(1,0))$ either contains $\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$ or is $\{p\}$.
In the former case, $g(1,0)$ is trivial, a contradiction.
In the latter case, for some suitable $t$, $1$ is a fixed point of $g(1,t)$ so $g(1,t)$ foxes every point in $\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$, hence $g(1,t)$ is the identity, a contradiction.
If $f(1,0,0)$ is a product of two $p$-cycles, we can assume that it is $(1\,2\,\ldots\,p)(p+1\,\ldots\,2p)$. Let $Z$ be the centralizer. If $\tau \in Z$, then $\tau$ either preserves $\{1,\ldots,p\}$ and $\{p+1,\ldots,2p\}$ or it exchanges them. Hence $Z$ has an index $2$ subgroup isomorphic to the square of the centralizer of $(1\,\ldots\,p)$ in $S_p$, which is cyclic of order $p$.
The argument in the first case shows that we need an injective morphism $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \times \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow Z$, which is impossible since $4 \nmid |Z|$.
Conclusion: the only cases where the embedding is impossible are the prime powers and the $n=2p$ with $p$ a Fermat prime.

This is a good question.
As you alluded, it will work with the holomorph.
For the direct product,  I suspect not.  For instance if $n=p$ is prime,  you'll need to find an abelian subgroup of $\mathscr S_p$ with order $p(p-1).$
